# Проверка последовательности чисел на возрастание/убывание

Tags: java

Само задание:

> reads a positive integer number n
>    reads n integer values and:
>   o displays the message “ascending sequence” if every number of the sequence (beyond the first one) is larger than the previous one
>   o displays the message “descending sequence” if every number of the sequence (beyond the first one) is smaller than the previous one
>   o displays the message “neither ascending nor descending sequence” if none of the two conditions above is satisfied
>   Example: assume n=10 and the following 10 numbers introduced: -2 5 7 13 18 24 40 56 90 137. Then, the program must print out the message: “ascending sequence”.

- Зная только основы Java, можно ли написать лучше чем моя писанина? Лучше - меньше, логичнее
- У меня выходит за пределы массива. Как исправить?

Код, который получился у меня:

```
public static void sequence() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Количество цифр");
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    int[] array = new int[n];
    int a;
    for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
        System.out.println("Введите число: ");
        array[i] = a = scanner.nextInt(); 
    }
    if (array[1] > array[2]) {
        for (int i = 2; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (i == array[n - 1]) {
                if (array[n - 2] > array[n - 1]) {
                    System.out.println("Восходящая");
                }
            } else if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println("Нет последовательности");
        }
    }
    if (array[1] < array[2]) {
        for (int i = 2; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (i == array[n - 1]) {
                if (array[n - 2] > array[n - 1]) {
                    System.out.println("Восходящая");
                }
            } else if (array[i] < array[i + 1]) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println("Нет последовательности");
        }
    }
```

Всем спасибо, исправил код, за пределы не выхожу, но не выдает результат всего сравнения. Думаю дальше

Comment: Ну вообще, ты трижды прогоняешь один массив циклом, можно сократить и делать сравнения сразу при вводе, понятность кода уменьшится, но его кол-во заметно сократится

Comment: и да, ты добавил два одинаковых участка кода

Comment: Не экономьте на пробелах...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ отметьте его, как принятый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде из вопроса есть несколько ошибок, поэтому предложу переписанный вариант, который в том числе и покороче:

```
public static void sequence()
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Количество чисел");
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    int[] array = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Введите число: ");
        array[i] = scanner.nextInt(); 
    }

    if (array[0] == array[1])
    {
        System.out.println("Нет последовательности");
        return;
    }
    boolean isAscending = array[0] < array[1];
    for (int i = 2; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if ((array[i - 1] >= array[i] && isAscending) ||
                (array[i - 1] <= array[i] && !isAscending))
        {
            System.out.println("Нет последовательности");
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(isAscending ? "Восходящая" : "Нисходящая");
}
```

- По первой паре элементов массива определяем, будем проверять массив/последовательность на возрастание или на убывание
- Если какой-то элемент не удовлетворяет проверке, то прекращаем проверку и выводим, что порядка в последовательности нет
- Если массив успешно проверен целиком, то выводим проверяемый порядок

---

P.S. По заданию непонятно нужно ли обрабатывать случай `n = 1` и что в этом случае выводить.

---

Можно несколько укоротить код алгоритма в ущерб понятности (плюс разница соседних чисел не должна быть меньше `Integer.MIN_VALUE` и больше `Integer.MAX_VALUE`):

```
int signum = Integer.signum(array[1] - array[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
{
    if ((array[i] - array[i - 1]) * signum <= 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Нет последовательности");
        return;
    }
}
System.out.println(signum == 1 ? "Восходящая" : "Нисходящая");
```

Comment: Не учитывая первое число, нужно просто исправить array[0] на 1?

Comment: @ShakhzodYakubov а почему вы не хотите учитывать первое число? В задании его нужно учитывать. _"beyond the first one"_ в данном контексте говорит о том, что первое число не должно быть больше/меньше предыдущего. И это логично, так как у первого числа попросту нет предыдущего.

Comment: блин точно, спасибо что отозвались сейчас буду разбираться. Я читал про boolean но никогда не использовал его

Comment: @ShakhzodYakubov единственное что мне не нравится сейчас в решении моём - кажется, что в задании для последовательности `1 1 1` ответом должно быть "Нет последовательности". Поправлю код.

Answer (score 1):

Нумерация массива начинается с 0 элемента,а не с 1. Таким образом,если в массиве 10 элементов, то нумерация 0..9, а в Вашем случае везде 0..10. Следовательно, решением проблемы является правильная установка границ итерации.

```
for (int i = 2; i < array.length - 1; i++)
```

А именно,выходит за пределы массива у вас в этой строке `else if (array[i] > array[i + 1])`

Comment: А про то,чтобы сделать код проще,я,наверное,соглашусь с тем,что можно проверять сразу при вводе чисел. То есть, вы можете при добавлении чисел в массив в тот же блок сделать проверку на свою последовательность, и, допустим, добавить флаг (*boolean ascending*). И по окончании ввода, если все введенные проверки истины, то флаг будет true, а значит восходящая последовательность. Как только проверка не будет пройдена, флаг false и нет последовательности.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Количество чисел");

    int[] array = new int[scanner.nextInt()];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Введите число: ");
        array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }

    int [] val = IntStream.of(array).sorted().toArray();

    if(Arrays.equals(array, val)) {
        System.out.println("Восходящая");
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < val.length / 2; i++) {
        int tmp = val[i];
        val[i] = val[val.length - i - 1];
        val[val.length - i - 1] = tmp;
    }
    if(Arrays.equals(array, val)) 
        System.out.println("Нисходящая");
    else
        System.out.println("Нет последовательности.");
```

С начало вводится содержимое `array`. После создается копия `array` - `val`. Сначала `val` сортируется по восходящей и потом если они совпадают выводим "Восходящая". Если нет `val` переворачивается и сравнивается с `array`. Если они совпадают это значить, что `array` нисходящий и выведется "Нисходящая". Если же нет то выведется "Нет последовательности".

Плюсом такого способа в том, что мы не прибегаем к циклам (за исключением переворачивания массива, но такой метод есть во всех проектах) и такой код легче понять.

Comment: Все бы хорошо, только я как новичок в Java(и в программировании) не знаю что такое IntStream и далее) Но за ответ спасибо, буду читать что это такое

Comment: @ShakhzodYakubov Эту строку можно заменить на: `int [] val = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length; Arrays.sort(val)`